# Como apagar um elemento em específico do <select>? (Javascript, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de deletar por ip cada um dos específicos objetos que o  possui.

```
 `<tr class="trAdminEdit"><td><div class="input-field col s12">
            <select id="select` + index + `" class="localAdminSelection adminEdit">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
              <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            <i id="apagarAdmin" onClick = 'removeAdmin()'>blocked</i>
            </select>
            </div></td></tr>`
```

e minha função tá assim

```
function removeAdmin(event, id){
        if($('.adminEdit').length > 2){
        $('.trAdminEdit').parent().parent().remove();
        console.log('foi')
        if ($('.adminEdit').length == 2)
        $('#apagarAdmin').css('display','none');
        if ($('.adminEdit').length < {{count($users)}} && $('#apagarAdmin').css('display') == 'none')
        $('#apagarAdmin').css('display','inline-block');

      }
    }
```

porém a função no momento apaga todos os administradores e não o correspondente do qual eu aperto o botão.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente com a função assim:

```
function removeAdmin(){
    let opcaoSelecionada = $('.adminEdit').find(":selected"); // aqui vai buscar o elemento
    if(opcaoSelecionada && opcaoSelecionada.length > 0){ //verifica que o elemento existe e que tem opção selecionada
        opcaoSelecionada.remove(); // aqui remove o elemento
    }
}
```

E o HTML deverá estar assim:

```
`<tr class="trAdminEdit"><td><div class="input-field col s12">
    <td>
        <select id="select` + index + `" class="localAdminSelection adminEdit">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
              <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <i id="apagarAdmin" onClick = 'removeAdmin()'>blocked</i>
    </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: Agradeço muito a resposta, mas infelizmente ele continua apagando todos os admins da seleção, queria lembrar que essa html ela é um append de outra função

Comment: Consegue colocar o código no (https://codepen.io/pen/ ) é mais fácil para perceber como têm o seu código a executar. Ou então edite a pergunta e adicione todo o seu código incluido print do mesmo renderizado.